# What is "soft skill"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, phrases, idioms

Please elaborate what does it mean by *soft skill* in term of English language.

Answer (score 7):

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soft_skill) a "soft skill" is

> A personal skill that is usually interpersonal, non-specialized, and difficult to quantify, such as leadership or responsibility.

Contrast this with a "hard skill":

> A technical skill, not one that is interpersonal

Soft skills are those needed when dealing with people and emotions which are "soft" when compared with technical things which are "hard".

Also, "soft vs hard" does not refer to difficulty. In fact the soft skills are often more difficult to acquire (i.e. "harder") than hard skills.

The sexist among us might say that women are naturally better at soft skills while men favor hard skills. This "observation" is the basis for many sitcoms. Indeed much of the humor in the show "[Bones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bones_%28TV_series%29#Cast_and_characters)" comes from the tough (male) FBI agent having far better soft skills than the detached (female) scientist.

Comment: There's this other show I like watching where the roles are completely inverted: the gal is a tough CIA agent while the guy is her rather emotional asset.